# "more than that" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Over the course of those generations, of course, many more Agta children will continue to hear many more instructive stories: of the sun and the moon — a man and a woman — who fight to a draw in their battle for the sky and choose to cooperate to share the day and the night; of the monkey who became a hero for killing a giant, but was kept wise and humble with the knowledge that all monkeys — even him — must still fear the eagle. All of the stories will merely be make-believe — **and all of them will be much more than that too**.

Does anyone know what the meaning of "**and all of them will be much more than that too.**" in the last sentence of this context is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stories may be make-believe, but ALSO much more than make-believe (***that*** in the sentence):

It will among other teach them the morals of the Agta, the myths and how they see the world around them. Possibly even prepare them for other skills - how to spot certain foods, teach them more words in their language etc.

Comment: +1 It's always good to have a person who can explain everything like 2+2.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means "**There will be a lot more to merely pretending that the stories that are not real are real or exciting**".

"**more than**" is a comparative degree *(phrase of "**more**")*. If something is more than a particular thing, it has greater value or importance than this thing. With "**more than that**" it means that there is more *(something else)* beyond what was mentioned earlier.

> You use "**more than**" to say that something is true to a greater degree than is necessary or than average. *([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/more-than))*

Examples:

- Other things matter **more than** you do.
- After all, he'd been **more than** generous when the money was good.

> "**more than**" may also mean "**very**" *([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-than))*

As for the word "**make-believe**" - *believing or imagining things that appear to be attractive or exciting, but are not real* *([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-believe))*.

Comment: I think the actual meaning of the words were clear.